# Передаются одни и те же данные через jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте, создал опрос. Но почему то, какой бы пункт опроса не был выбран, вариант на почту приходит всегда только первый. (Это из инклудов с типом radio). Из-за чего такое происходит? не могли бы вы помочь в этом плане? Вот структура опроса:

```
    <div id="opros">
<div class="three_quarter">
<h1>Пацаны это опрос!</h1>
<img src="images/opros.png" style="float: right;" width="320" alt="">
<div><b>Введите Ф И О:</b><input id="fio" type="text" name="fio" /><br /></div>

<div style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;"><b>Вопросы:</b></div>

<div style="padding: 10px 0;"><b>Вы:</b> 
Мужчина<input id="sex" type=radio name="sex" value="Мужчина"> 
Женщина<input id="sex" type=radio name="sex" value="Женщина"></div>

<div style="padding: 10px 0;"> 
<b>Зачем вы поступали в Универ?</b><br>
<input id="zachem" type=radio name="zachem" value="Чтобы учится и узнавать новое!"> Чтобы учится и узнавать новое!<br>
<input id="zachem" type=radio name="zachem" value="Познакомится с новыми людьми."> Познакомится с новыми людьми.<br>
<input id="zachem" type=radio name="zachem" value="Просто получить диплом, я и так знаю больше чем преподают!"> Просто получить диплом, я и так знаю больше чем преподают!<br>
</div>

<div style="padding: 10px 0;"> 
<b>Оцените уровень получаемых знаний в нашем университете:</b><br>
<input id="raiting" type=radio name="raiting" value="Ужасно преподают, ничё не понятно!"> Ужасно преподают, ничё не понятно!<br>
<input id="raiting" type=radio name="raiting" value="Преподают нормально, но можно и лучше!"> Преподают нормально, но можно и лучше!<br>
<input id="raiting" type=radio name="raiting" value="Мне всё нравится, преподают отлично, всё понятно!"> Мне всё нравится, преподают отлично, всё понятно!<br>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
<div style="padding: 10px 0; float: left;"> 
<b>Как вам сайт?</b><br>
<input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="Очень плохо"> Очень плохо<br>
<input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="Не надо"> Не надо<br>
<input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="Общепит"> Общепит<br>
<input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="В самый раз"> В самый раз<br>
<input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="Очень круто"> Очень круто<br>
<input id="rait" type=radio name="rait" value="ШЕДЕВР!"> ШЕДЕВР!<br>
</div>

<p id="al" style="margin-top: 50px; width: auto; margin-left: 250px; color: blue; font-size: 24px;"></p>

</div>
<div style="clear: both;"><input id="opr" type="submit" value="Отправить" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Скрипт jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#opr").click(function(){
var fio = $("#fio").val();
var sex = $("#sex").val();
var zachem = $("#zachem").val();
var raiting = $("#raiting").val();
var rait = $("#rait").val();

$.post("../scripts/mail.php",
{
fio: fio,
sex: sex,
zachem: zachem,
raiting: raiting,
rait: rait 
},
function(data){
$("#al").html(data);
}
);
});
});
</script>
```

И сама пхп отправка письма:

```
    if (isset($_POST)) {

    $fio = ($_POST['fio']);
    $sex = ($_POST['sex']);
    $zachem = ($_POST['zachem']);
    $raiting = ($_POST['raiting']);
    $rait = ($_POST['rait']);

        if ($fio != ''){

            $to = "sfasffhdf@mail.ru";
            $subject = "Robot";
            $message = "<html><head></head><body> 
                        На сайте ответили на вопросы! <br><br> 
                        <table border=1> 
                        <tr><td width=10><b>Полученные ответы:</b></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><b>Ф И О:</b></td><td>".$fio."</td><td>".$sex."</td>
                        <tr><td><b>Зачем вы поступали в Универ:</b></td><td> ".$zachem."<br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><b>Получаемые знания:</b></td><td> ".$raiting." </td></tr>
                        <tr><td><b>Оценка сайту:</b></td><td> ".$rait." </td></tr>
                        </tr></table><br> 
                        </body></html>";
            $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
            $headers .= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n";
            $headers .= "Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com\r\n";
            $headers .= "Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com\r\n";
            mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            echo "Спасибо за то, что прошли наш опрос, эта информация очень важна для нас!";

        } else {
            echo "Вы не заполнили поле Ф И О !";
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых как сказали выше, ошибка с одинаковыми ID, но + проблема что вы обращаетесь к самому первому инпуту, а надо выбирать тот который выбран пользователем (:checked)

```
$("#zachem:checked").val()
```

Comment: Всё понял, просто я новичок не знал что необходимо такое добавить!))

Answer (score 1):

потому что у вариантов выбора, таких как радиокнопки, одинаковые id. А это недопустимо. У них должны быть name одинаковые.

Comment: @Елена Левина, скажите, а как описать их имя в переменную в js ? Я только по id умею:(

Comment: имелось в виду — как выбрать по имени? $('[name=zachem]')